# Accessing derived objects in boost::ptr_vector

Tags: c++, boost, ptr-vector

I am using a boost::ptr_vector < class A > , which I also use to store objects of class B : public class A. I want to be able to access the class B objects in the vector; how do I cast to get access?

Comment: The fact that you need to down cast is a design smell. You should change your design so that this isn't necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally, `A` should provide a virtual interface that allows you to access the parts of `B` that you need.  If you need to access the actual `B` objects, you would need to use `dynamic_cast` on the reference yielded by an iterator into the container (you could use `static_cast` if you knew with certainty that the iterator actually pointed at a `B` object):

```
// Create a container and insert a new element into it:
boost::ptr_vector<A> s;
s.push_back(new B());

// Get a reference to that element we just inserted:
B& b_ref = dynamic_cast<B&>(*s.begin());
```

If you wanted to iterate over all the `B` elements in the container (and skip over any non-`B` elements), you could do that fairly easily using a combination of Boost's `transform_iterator` (to convert each `A&` to a `B&`) and `filter_iterator` (to skip over any non-`B` elements in the container).

Comment: If not all objects in the container are (derived from) `B`, you'd better `dynamic_cast` a pointer, e.g. `dynamic_cast<B*>(&*s.begin())`.  It will yield a null pointer when the type didn't match, unlike the reference cast which will throw exceptions.

Comment: On further reading, don't `ptr_vector` iterators dereference to `T*` rather than `T&`?  [The docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/ptr_container/doc/reversible_ptr_container.html) say `typedef T* value_type;`  So `dynamic_cast<B*>(*s.begin())`

Comment: @Ben: the `value_type` of a pointer container is a `T*`, but iterators "auto-dereference" (and have a `value_type` of `T`).  You're right that in many cases a `dynamic_cast<T*>` would be preferrable, especially since it can then be used as the condition of an `if`  (e.g., `if (B* b_ptr = dynamic_cast<B*>(&*s.begin())) { }`), which provides an implicit null check.

Comment: What if I don't want to iterate over the ptr_vector? What if I just want to access a single element and cast it to class B?

Comment: `operator[]` also returns a reference, so:  `dynamic_cast<B&>(s[N])`.  (or `dynamic_cast<B*>(&s[N])`).